# <apply-template> output into a variable and accessing it

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to identify and copy number of elements by using  and store the output in a variable. But even with exsl:node-set() function the output is considered as single node/element and I can't access individual elements in it.

I'm using standard xslt processors in Eclipse which are JRE Instance Default and Xalan 2.7.1

Here is a simple XML file that I'm using as an example of a bigger task:

```xml
<root>
    <group>
        <type>2</type>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
    </group>
</root>
```

Here is xslt:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <root> 
        <xsl:variable name="items">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//item" />
        </xsl:variable>

        items count: <xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($items))"/>
        item output: <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($items)"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It appears like node-set() does not convert the tree fragment into node set, but just creates a single node/block.

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

    items count: 1
    item output:
</root>
```

How do I actually get a node set of multiple elements to further work with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @imran the desired output is number of <item> nodes which in this case is 3 (not 1 as it is now) and the possibility to traverse through them in <for-each select="$items">. Count and value-of in the example are just to illustrate that the content of $items cannot be processed further.

Answer (score 2):

For the count, do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($items)/item)"/>
```

Otherwise you're counting the parent variable, of which there's only one. Similarly, if you want to process the items in the variable, you will need to do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($items)/item"/>
```

---

For the contents of the variable, try:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($items)"/>
```

or just:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$items"/>
```

(you don't need to convert a result tree fragment to a node-set in order to copy it).

What you do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($items)"/>
```

retrieves the string-value of the entire variable, which is "456" (not empty as you report).

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Indeed the key was that the variable had a root node itself and changing to exsl:node-set($items)/item did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update:

Due to a technical hiccup on my end, I failed to catch that this wouldn't work with XSL version 1.0.  Both Michael and I noted that your XPath is incorrect.  My example below only works with XSL version 2.0 or newer, so use Michael's code for version 1.0.

---

The key problem is your XPath expressions for dealing with your variable.

When you declare your variable like this:

```xml
    <xsl:variable name="items">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//item" />
    </xsl:variable>
```

... what you get is an in-memory variable `$items` that has this:

```xml
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
```

When I run your code, the place where you just plop out the value using `xsl:value-of`, I just get the default behavior where XSL spits out the string value of the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

        items count: 1
        item output: 456</root>
```

Since I get slightly different output, I have to ask -- what XSL processor are you using?

That aside, this variable is notably *not* a node-set, but rather a **document fragment**.  So if you want to access any specific `<item>` element within that variable, you need to treat the variable name as the root.  So if you have `count($items)`, you just get a count of 1, since there's only one root element.

To count the `<item>` elements *within* `$items`, you need to specify the correct XPath: `count($items/item)`.

Also, to output the string value of the variable, you don't need to change it to a nodeset.

Try this for your root template:

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <root> 
        <xsl:variable name="items">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//item" />
        </xsl:variable>

        items count: <xsl:value-of select="count($items/item)"/>
        item output: <xsl:value-of select="$items"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

My output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

        items count: 3
        item output: 456</root>
```

Comment: The variable is actually a *result tree fragment*. And for this reason `<xsl:value-of select="count($items/item)"/>` cannot work in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- How confusing.  In OxygenXML, if you add `version="1.0"` in the `<xsl>` tag, the built-in validation respects that and will complain if you add anything beyond XSL 1.0.  However, the actual runtime debugging doesn't respect this.  Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, separately, it seems the `xslt-1.0` tag should be added to this thread?  I'm not familiar with Eclipse or Xalan -- are they limited to 1.0?

Comment: Xalan is XSLT 1.0. Eclipse is an IDE, not an XSLT processor.